# The result is not as intended, the output is a bound method error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```py
class LoggedError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)
    
class Member(object):
    nextId = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Member.nextId
        Member.nextId += 1
        
    def getId(self):
        return self.id
    
class Customer(Member):
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.logged = False
    
    def signin(self, email, password):
        if (self.email == email and self.password == password):
            if (self.logged == True):
                raise LoggedError("Already signed in.")
            else:
                self.logged = True
                return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def signout(self):
        if (self.logged == False):
            raise LoggedError("Already signed out.")
        else:
            self.logged = False
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
    
c1 = Customer("abc@abc.com", "12341234")
c2 = Customer("def@def.com", "56785678")
c3 = Customer("hello@world.com", "qwerty")

print("Customer 1 is {}".format(c1))
print("Customer 2 is {}".format(c2))
print("Customer 3 is {}".format(c3))
print("Customer 1's id is {}".format(c1.getId))
print("Customer 2's id is {}".format(c2.getId))
print("Customer 3's id is {}".format(c3.getId))

try:
    print("Customer 1 sign-in {}".format(c1.signin("abc@abc.com", "12341234")))
except LoggedError as e:
    print(e)
    
try:
    print("Customer 2 sign-out {}".format(c2.signout()))
except LoggedError as e:
    print(e)
    
try:
    print("Customer 3 sign-in {}".format(c3.signin("abc@abc.com", "12341234")))
except LoggedError as e:
    print(e)
```

The output of the above code is:

Customer 1 is abc@abc.com
Customer 2 is def@def.com
Customer 3 is hello@world.com
Customer 1's id is <bound method Member.getId of <__main__.Customer object at 0x000002354D7674F0>>
Customer 2's id is <bound method Member.getId of <__main__.Customer object at 0x000002354D63C850>>
Customer 3's id is <bound method Member.getId of <__main__.Customer object at 0x000002354D731D60>>
Customer 1 sign-in True
'Already signed out.'
Customer 3 sign-in False
'Already signed in.'

However, this result is a bound error and is incorrect. The correct result is:

Customer 1 is abc@abc.com
Customer 2 is def@def.com
Customer 3 is hello@world.com
Customer 1's id is 0
Customer 2's id is 1
Customer 3's id is 2
Customer 1 sign-in True
'Already signed out.'
Customer 3 sign-in False
'Already signed in.'

I wonder how to fix the above Python code to get the above result.

Comment: you are forgetting the parentheses after getId

Comment: It's `c1.getId()`, you forgot to call the method.

Comment: You have to explicitly call the `__init__` constructor of the superclass to initialize the fields defined there e.g. `self.id`

``` python
class Customer(Member):
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        super(Customer, self).__init__()
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.logged = False
    
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually call the method:

```
print("Customer 1's id is {}".format(c1.getId()))
...
```